# Flink 1.15.2 OOM issue due to RocksDB

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, rocksdb

I am working on migrating my team's service to Flink 1.15.2 from Flink 1.8. I've had luck running new Flink on a single host (1 jobmanager and 1 taskmanager on the same node), however on a multi-node cluster where I have 1 jobmanager and 3 taskmanagers, the Taskmanagers dont seem to process anything beyond source event deserialization. I think this maybe due to an out of memory issue caused by RocksDB backend. I have tried numerous combinations suggested in https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/ops/state/large_state_tuning/#tuning-rocksdb-memory but they dont work. Does anyone have any suggestions or similar experiences with RocksDB backend memory going out of control and killing taskmanager hosts?

All the hosts are r7i.12xlarge, with 48 cores and 384Gig memory.

I have tried the options

```
state.backend.rocksdb.memory.managed: false
```

and also have tried increasing managed memory to about 90% of Flink total memory (note that we do not use Kubernetes, its a standalone deployment). I have also tried disabling RocksDB block-cache as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75883508 but have no improvement. I have also tried solutions listed in [Flink RocksDB custom options factory config error disable block cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75896760/flink-rocksdb-custom-options-factory-config-error-disable-block-cache)

Currently the Flink job starts with high backpressure since our source is Kinesis data with 1 day minimum retention and for taskmanager, it does not move past deserializing events (whereas Jobmanager does). Throughput is affected badly, and after minutes its only jobmanager trying to cope up with traffic.

Comment: Perhaps this is caused by the memory corruption that affected some releases before 1.17: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-30321

Comment: I see that my state-backend pom.xml shows:

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.ververica</groupId>
   <artifactId>frocksdbjni</artifactId>
   <version>6.20.3-veverica-1.0</version>
  </dependency>

Let me see if upgrading it to 6.20.3-veverica-2.0 will solve the problem.

Comment: @DavidAnderson the solution does not work past some point. I made some progress in processing some records through mapper steps in Flink but after some minutes, the records get stuck and taskmanager gets out of memory

Comment: I wonder if you may've misdiagnosed the problem. What you've said about the cause of the backpressure doesn't sound right -- sources can't cause backpressure. And there have been many changes since 1.8, such as switching to making event time the default time characteristic, and the new sources and sinks, that you might need to make some adaptations for.