# Flink high ram usage

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

We have a flink pipeline that reads values (sensor values) from a pubsub topic and creates so called 30 sec buckets. These buckets represent average values for a 30sec window for a specific sensorId.

Flink is running on a kubernetes cluster and I am wondering if the ram usage that we are seeing is the normal behaviour or if the pipeline needs to be improved.

We have 22 taskmanagers active, averaging 6.5 GB / 16GB per pod. Parallelism = 6

Amount of incoming messages: around 3k / sec.

Pipeline code:

```
        Window<KV<String, DeviceData>> window30Sec = Window.<KV<String, DeviceData>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(30)))
            .triggering(
                    AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                            .withLateFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(15)))
            )
            .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(30))
            .accumulatingFiredPanes();


        PCollectionTuple collectionTuple = pipeline.apply("Read raw data",
                    PubsubIO.
                            readStrings().
                            fromSubscription(rawDataSub))
            .apply("Parse to DeviceData", new PubSubMessageToDeviceData(tagA));

    PCollection<KV<String, DeviceData>> pCollection = collectionTuple.get(tagA);
    pCollection
            .apply("Apply 30sec Window", window30Sec)
            .apply("Group by inputId", GroupByKey.create())
            .apply("Collect created buckets", ParDo.of(new GatherBuckets(30)))
            .apply("Send to Pub-Sub", PubsubIO.writeStrings().to(createdBucketTopic));
```

Ram / CPU usage (a very little CPU is used, a lot ~100gb of RAM):
[image]

Are we doing anything wrong?

Comment: I don't see where you're setting up watermarks - are you using processing time? And if so, what's the meaning of setting an allowed lateness of 30 minutes?

Comment: This is part of the new PubSubMessageToDeviceData() call - we output with c.outputWithTimestamp(KV.of(sourceId, data), new org.joda.time.Instant(millis)); where millis is the timestamp of the recorded timestamp. Allowed lateness is meant to allow late data up to max 30 min to be considered for bucket calculation.

Comment: It looks like you're using Apache Beam - I would tag the question with that, to help get the right people involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [Flink job requiring a lot of memory despite using rocksdb state backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70986020/flink-job-requiring-a-lot-of-memory-despite-using-rocksdb-state-backend)

RocksDB is using all the memory it will get.
We have set following values

```
taskmanager.memory.process.size: 4g
taskmanager.memory.managed.fraction: 0.2
```

And are achieving our desired results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Beam user, but with Flink if you are doing time-based windows with allowed lateness, and you've got a large lateness value (30 minutes, in your case), and you're not doing any reducing in your window, then you could be accumulating a lot of state. But since you say you're using RocksDB, my only guess is that Beam+Flink tries to use all available memory for RocksDB.

Comment: Is the backend defined in the Job Manager state.backend configuration key? If yes - it is rocksdb in our case. Which strategy could we use to reduce the states? To my understanding even with early firings the state will be kept until the window has been fully closed

Comment: Also I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70986020/flink-job-requiring-a-lot-of-memory-despite-using-rocksdb-state-backend it seems rocksdb will use all memory it gets. We need to test in the next days